# Is column selection in pytorch differentiable?

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation

Is column selection in Pytorch differentiable? for eg if I want to select a single column from each row to make a new row X 1 array and then backdrop using this new array, will the backdrop work properly?

```
qvalues = qvalues[range(5),[0,1,0,1,0]]
```

if element selection is done as shown above from a 5*2 tensor?

Comment: please mark the question as solved if the answer helped you :)

Answer (score 23):

I think it is. Let me make an example with code.

First we create the `qvalues` tensor and we say we want to compute its gradients

```
qvalues = torch.rand((5, 5), requires_grad=True)
```

Now we create the tensor to index it and obtain a 5x2 tensor as its result (I think this is the same selection you wanted to perform with `qvalues[range(5),[0,1,0,1,0]]`):

```
y = torch.LongTensor([1, 3])
new_qvalues = qvalues[:, y]
```

We see that the slice `new_qvalues` of the original `qvalues` will compute the gradient

```
print(new_qvalues.requires_grad) # True
```

Now we perform our mathematical operations. In this example code, I am doing the square of `new_qvalues` because we know that its gradient (derivative) will be `2 * new_qvalues`.

```
qvalues_a = new_qvalues ** 2
```

Now, we have to compute the gradients of `qvalues_a`. We set `retain_graph=True` to store the `.grad` of each tensor and avoid freeing the buffers on the backward pass.

```
qvalues_a.backward(torch.ones(new_qvalues.shape), retain_graph=True)
```

Now, we can go back to the original `qvalues` and see if the gradients have been calculated

```
print(qvalues)
print(qvalues.grad)

# result of the print statemets

#tensor([[ 0.9677,  0.4303,  0.2036,  0.3870,  0.6085],
#    [ 0.8876,  0.8695,  0.2028,  0.3283,  0.1560],
#    [ 0.1764,  0.4718,  0.5418,  0.5167,  0.6200],
#    [ 0.7610,  0.9322,  0.5584,  0.5589,  0.8901],
#    [ 0.8146,  0.7296,  0.8036,  0.5277,  0.5754]])

#tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.8606,  0.0000,  0.7739,  0.0000],
#    [ 0.0000,  1.7390,  0.0000,  0.6567,  0.0000],
#    [ 0.0000,  0.9435,  0.0000,  1.0334,  0.0000],
#    [ 0.0000,  1.8645,  0.0000,  1.1178,  0.0000],
#    [ 0.0000,  1.4592,  0.0000,  1.0554,  0.0000]])
```

We can observe how the gradients have been computed only in the selected indexes. To be sure about it we create some *fast* test by comparing that the value of `qvalues.grad` for the selected slice is equal to the derivate `2 * new_qvalues`.

```
assert torch.equal(qvalues.grad[:, y], 2 * new_qvalues)
```

And it does not throw any error, so I would assume that you can get the gradient of the slice.

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer. I was wondering if it is possible to use different disjoint slices of a tensor as input in different batches. The problem I am facing is that since the gradients are associated with the original tensor only (and not the slices), after the first slice is used in a batch, the results are freed and I get the error of doing backward twice: `RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.`

Comment: If I set the `retain_graph=True` as mentioned in the error, then I get another error: `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation...` which is also due to different slices being used in different batches and backward being called. I don't know what is the proper way to do this. Please let me know if you have a solution/suggestion. I posted a question but it was closed, so I am not sure where to seek help.